# Create a SQL Compact Editon database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I have a problem with creating SQL Compact Edition.

I have been working on a C# project and I have been trying to make a .sdf file on Visual Studio 2013. I have installed the SQL Compact Edition but I can't make a database. I searched in the Internet and I found that to make this type of file I have to click on Local database when I add a new item but I don't have it in the list.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install my free "SQL Server Compact Toolbox" extension, and use that to create the database file.